# Rails & Resque: Exception handling methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm playing around with resque for the first time. The gem itself is fine, but out of the box, I don't have any effective way of identifying errors/exceptions thrown from within resque tasks. The redis/resque worker itself doesn't seem to log (or throw exceptions), which means if there's an error in the resqued code, my only means of finding it is PRYing about until I find the error. So: in short, is there any way to throw exceptions in a resque queue? If not, is setting up a logger the way most folks approach resque debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resque does provide a [nice UI](https://github.com/blog/543-new-resque-web-ui) with the jobs working and failed, and it shows already some informations about the exceptions. You can configure it in your routes with something like :

`mount Resque::Server, at: '/admin/jobs'`

Is this not enough, or are you not using it ?

This being said, I would urge you to setup a logger for your jobs anyway, you should want both options available.